# android apk resource

Tags: android

Recently I watch a video about android app framework.(google I/O 2008)
In the video, the host says that an apk is a collection of component.
My question is, when I'm installing an apk, which directory(/data??) will the resource(such as class.dex and other resources file) be stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.apk` files themselves are stored in `/data/app`, while the `.dex` files in `/data/dalvik-cache`

**Addition**: App data is stored in `/data/data/[PAKAGE_NAME]`

If you are curious about what's a `.apk` file: it's just a regular `zip` file!
As such, you can open it with 7-zip or winrar and look inside. You will find:

- `META-INF` folder: that's the signature of the package
- `res` folder: where you will find some `.xml` and all the `.png` files (and possibly `.mp3` or whatever the package uses). Note that those `.xml` files will be already compiled, not human-readable.
- `AndroidManifest.xml` :as the name implies, the manifest.
- `classes.dex` file: all the java classes compiled to byte code
- `resources.arsc` file: the layout `.xml` files

Comment: Ok, so when I'm installing my .apk. Will the android system unzip the file and store in some places.

Comment: Yes. You can read about the dex files here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6925/what-is-the-difference-between-odexed-and-deodexed-roms (although it mostly applies to system apks). But if you just care about deploying your own app, then just let android do the stuff for you. You are not required to provide any installation mechanism.